# how to connect to hotmail server?

Tags: asp.net-3.5, integration

i am developing a website in wich i want to connect to hotmail server to read and send emails through my website but i am not able to connect to server..i am using pop3 and smtp 
i am getting error as below

[System.Net.Sockets.SocketException] = {"The requested name is valid and was found in the database, but it does not have the correct associated data being resolved for"}

StackTrace = "   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)\r\n   at System.Net.Dns.Resolve(String hostName)\r\n   at Pop3.Pop3Client.GetClientSocket() in C:\Documents and Settings\DST\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\hot...

TargetSite = {System.Net.IPHostEntry InternalGetHostByName(System.String, Boolean)}

i am gettin this error when i call a function as

IPHostEntry hostEntry = null;

```
    hostEntry = Dns.Resolve(m_credential.Server);
```

please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you might be way off from your goal and perhaps making things much too complicated than necessary. Sending email from .Net via the [SmtpClient class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(VS.80).aspx) is a fairly simple process. Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(VS.80).aspx).

Here is a [nice-looking tutorial](http://www.dijksterhuis.org/using-csharp-to-send-an-e-mail-through-smtp/) for sending email via SmtpClient.

And here is a [sample for reading pop3 email](http://blog.rebex.net/news/archive/2007/05/14/howto-download-emails-from-gmail-account-in-csharp.aspx) from Gmail (should be easy to change to Hotmail.)

Good luck!